# kubectl config merge redirect not as expected

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to merge the kubectl config and redirect it to a file, the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

HOST_KUBECONFIG="$KUBECONFIG"
MY_KUBECONFIG=kube_config
export KUBECONFIG="$HOST_KUBECONFIG"
echo "$(kubectl config view --flatten)" > .kube_config_tmp
if [ -f "$MY_KUBECONFIG" ] ; then
  export KUBECONFIG="$MY_KUBECONFIG":.kube_config_tmp
else
  export KUBECONFIG=.kube_config_tmp
fi
kubectl config view --flatten  >file1

kubectl config view --flatten  > $MY_KUBECONFIG
```

It is strange that the result in file1 and MY_KUBECONFIG(kube_config) is different. 
In file1 can get the correct result ,but in MY_KUBECONFIG(kube_config) then content is always the same as KUBECONFIG.
Could someone explain that？

Comment: The first time run the code can get the same result but after I update something in kube_config and run the code again the result will be different.    If update the last line to `echo "$(kubectl config view --flatten)"  > $MY_KUBECONFIG` everything will goes well

Comment: How do you run your bash script, by sourcing it ?  

I tried following:  

1. unset KUBECONFIG:
2. source ./merge_k8s_cfg:
3. echo $KUBECONFIG:  .kube_config_tmp:
4. diff kube_config file1 -s //Files kube_config and file1 are identical:
5. kubectl config --kubeconfig=kube_config set-cluster dev --server=https://127.0.0.1 --insecure-skip-tls-verify:
6. diff kube_config file1 -s    //Can see diffs:
7. source ./merge_k8s_cfg:
8. echo $KUBECONFIG:  
  kube_config:.kube_config_tmp
9. cat kube_config //changes are gone:

Comment: sorry, but I cannot make somehow Comment formatting working as a block of code